# Does always weak entity need a partial key?

Tags: database-design

I have user who has profile (weak entity )

profile include Question and answers and QuesID

I am confused should I have partial key for profile or no because I do not think that I have attribute can be a key?

Comment: Partial key? Do you mean a composite key? A weak entity does not have to have a composite key.

Comment: I mean by partial key one or more attributes that uniquely identify a weak entity for a  owner entity.

Answer (score 4):

Typically a weak entity has a composite key consisting of the key of its parent entity plus one or more additional attributes. It doesn't have to be so. For example if a User entity can have at most just one Profile associated with it then the key of User could also be the key of Profile (i.e. with no additional attributes).

Answer (score 0):

The fact that Profile does not seem to need a partial key is because of the 1:1 relationship with user, thus a profile can be fully identified with the user key.

However, I would argue that having this Profile entity may not be necessary, as all its attributes can be moved to the User entity. I know that in practice it can be useful to have two tables to make request for some user data vs get the whole profile, but I would say that a conceptual modelling does not need to worry about these implementation issues.